# QGIS Export Line Direction Symbol from Labels

Tags: qgis

I have set up certain labels to show the Line Direction using the Line Direction Symbol in Label Formatting, with default `< and >` symbols. It works great, but I now want to export these symbols for use in a web map.

I have set both the Left and Right directions to 'Store in Project' but when I check the Auxiliary Layers they don't contain any features and just show `NULL` in the attributes table. The layers are set as Text Edit in the Attributes Form. I was hoping to use the `Field Calculator` to pull the Auxiliary data (< and > characters) into the main database for export.

I'm not sure what I am missing, any ideas? I am using QGIS V3.10.10

Comment: The line direction is inherently stored in the line geometry if you want to display it some symbology should be fine. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have created our basemap in QGIS and it is now being put into a webmap, I believe using Postgres database and leaflet (although this is not my areas of expertise). The developers are struggling to get line direction symbols to work on the webmap, so we thought we could add the line direction symbols to the database in QGIS and just use them as part of the annotation. I have actually managed this by exporting to DXF and then joining the DXF text fields to the origional database. Although I would much prefer to have an expression do this on the webmap if possible?